# SQL ignoring null value matching

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null

We have two tables, tableA as follows:
tableA:

```
╔═════╦═════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id1 ║ id2 ║ data1 ║ data2 ║ 
╠═════╬═════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1  ║  1  ║  aa1  ║  aa2  ║
║  2  ║  2  ║  bb1  ║  bb2  ║
║  3  ║  3  ║  cc1  ║  cc2  ║
║  4  ║  3  ║  null ║  null ║
╚═════╩═════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

id, id1 = id2, then the row has correct data, else id2 refers to row with correct data...

and tableB as follows:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ look1 ║ look2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║   1   ║   2   ║
║   2   ║   3   ║
║   3   ║   4   ║
║   4   ║  null ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

I need tableC(output) as follows, 
tableC:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ look1 ║ data1 ║ look2 ║ data2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║   1   ║  aa1  ║   2   ║  bb2  ║
║   2   ║  bb1  ║   3   ║  cc2  ║
║   3   ║  cc1  ║   4   ║  cc2  ║
║   4   ║  cc1  ║  null ║  null ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I tried this query:

```
Select tableB.look1, b.data1, tableB.look2, d.data2
from tableB, tableA a, tableA b, tableA c, tableA d
where
a.id2 = b.id2 --self join to skip to referencing row
and
a.id1 = tableB.look1
and
b.data1!=null;
and
c.id2 = d.id2
and
c.id1 = tableB.look2;
```

This gives me,

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ look1 ║ data1 ║ look2 ║ data2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║   1   ║  aa1  ║   2   ║  bb2  ║
║   2   ║  bb1  ║   3   ║  cc2  ║
║   3   ║  cc1  ║   4   ║  cc2  ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

4th value is lost, How can I get desired output?

Comment: `c.id1 = tableB.look2` When `look2` is `null` it cannot be equal to `id1`. Your expected fourth row makes no sense!

Comment: ^That is the problem, you see, it makes sense for 1st 3 rows, and I need null in output table when look2 is null

Comment: I think your login and query both are wrong. You can not connect look1=>4 with data1=>cc1

Comment: You need to use `left join` instead of `cross join` or `inner join`, such as:  `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM tablea As t1 left join tableb As t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.look1 ...`

Comment: that is what self join is for, id1 is a primary key, but two "real life" objects points to data1, so id2 is introduced, which refers to helps in refering to other rows,

Comment: @MaciejLos, this query is a part of HUGE query, can you help me with putting this in theta-style?